# Question related to partial ordering

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $Z^+$ denote the set of positive integers. We write m|n to denote the fact that m divides n, i.e., n = km for some k$\epsilon Z^+$

(a) Show that | defines a partial ordering on $Z^+$

(b) Does $Z^+$ contain either a maximal or minimal element relative to this partial ordering?

(c) Prove that any subset of $Z^+$ containing exactly two elements has a greatest lower bound and a least upper bound.

(d) For each of the following subsets of $Z^+$, determine whether or not it is a chain in $Z^+$, find a maximal and minimal element, an upper and lower bound, and a least upper bound:

(i) {1, 2, 4, 6, 8}.

(ii) {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}.

(iii) {3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18}.

(iv) {4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128}.

---

(a) part is easy.

(b) According to me 1 is a minimal element because a'R'1 $\Rightarrow$ a=1. Now for maximal element , you think of of any number but n'R'2n . But using Zorn's Lemma every chain of the  set have upper bound as L.C.M of all numbers in it so the set must contain a maximal element. So tell me where i am wrong and why ?(i think 2nd explanation is correct but i can't get a feeling).

(c) Will not every finite element subset satisfy this property ?

(d)Pls check my answer for this part , (i want to know if I understood the rules correctly)

(i) Not a chain,maximal elements are {8,6} and minimal elements are {1}, glb=1 , lub= 24 , 1 is also the smallest element.

(ii) Not a chain, maximal elements are {3,4,5} , minimal elements is {1}, glb =1 , lub =60  , 1 is the smallest element.

(iii) Not a chain, maximal elemets {12,15,18} and minimal elements ={3} ,glb =3 and lub= 180 , 3 is the smallest element .

(iv) Chain , maximal element is 128 and minimal element is 1 , glb = 1 and lub = 128  , 1 is the smallest element and 128 is the greatest element  .

---

Thanks for the help

Comment: (b)  What is an upper bound of the chain of all powers of 2?

Comment: @William Elliot , thankyou,could tell me about (c) part also